# PHP foreeach loop capture the first 9 chars

Tags: php

I have a MySQL query that returns data and I run a foreach loop to echo out the results.

Each row of data is a string and has a unique identifier at the start which is nine (9) characters long.

What I am trying to do is extract the first nine characters from each row and use it in a `$_GET` request. Below is my working data.

[image: Rows of data]

At the start of each row is the Unique identifier (nine characters) Example: `SeqID 0101`. Can I extract that code and use it in a `$_GET` on the View button:

```
foreach ($row as $k => $v)
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$k.'</td>
<td>'.$v.'</td>
<td><a href="imaint_failed_items_group_iframe.php?Seq=<?php echo $identifier;?>" target="_self"><img src="../../../nav/images/view_button.png"/></a></td>
</tr>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pupil already said you could use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
<?php foreach($row as $k => $v): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $k; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v; ?></td>
        <td><a href="imaint_failed_items_group_iframe.php?Seq=<?php echo substr($k, 0, 9); ?>" target="_self"><img src="../../../nav/images/view_button.png"/></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: substring should be of `$v` not of `$k`

Answer (score 4):

Use PHP [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$identifier = substr($v, 0, 9);
```

This will return first 9 characters.

`0` is start

AND `9` is length of characters.